# Simple online editor in javascript

Tags: javascript, editor, contenteditable, google-wave

I'm looking for some engine written in javascript that allows the user to write in a 'box'. The idea is to create something like Google docs but without the editing options (thus, not allowing bold and that stuff).

I'm not looking for something like the `contentEditable` option in javascript because it depends a bit on the browser. That's why I need some own implementation. The `WaveProtocol` is not what I'm looking for either.
It would be more something like [typewith.me](http://typewith.me) for example.

Do you guys know some engine or something I could use? With the client side part would be enough.

Thank's a lot!

Comment: `something like Google docs but without the editing options (thus, not allowing bold and that stuff)` So what are you looking for over a simple `<textarea>` ?

Comment: So will a `<textarea>` not do? Or do you have some hidden meaning?

Comment: The thing is that it'll be sending content to a server side and a textarea wouldn't do the trick. Before I start I'd need to know more efficient writing ways in a browser than a textarea.

Comment: @googol you can send the text in a textarea to your server

Comment: `<textarea>` + _AJAX_ which sends after a period of inactivity (3 seconds?) or `x` many changes since last update (500 chars?).

Comment: Yep, I know that. Thx for the comments but I'm looking for something more powerful than a textarea.

Comment: @googol maybe look into [javascript WYSIWYG editors](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/html5-wysiwyg/).

Comment: Yay! :D @jbabey I didn't know those things! I'm going to read some docs and maybe give it a try! Could you please publish that as an answer so I can rate it? Thank's a lot!

Comment: Almost all of the major WYSIWYG editors use `contenteditable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a [WYSIWYG editor](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/html5-wysiwyg/).

If I had to recommend one, I would use [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) as it is open source and well documented/supported.